# Retrieve an arraylist from JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a servlet that contains an `ArrayList`, and a JSP file that displays after the servlet. After the user clicks next on the `JSP` File, I go to a different servlet, which needs the `ArrayList` from the original Servlet.

How can I Use the JSP Page to retrieve that `Arraylist` ?

Currently I have The `ArrayList` as a hidden input in the JSP, but the new `Servlet` call will not retrieve that hidden input as an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Store `Arraylist` in Session scope.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, invoke the servlet again to get an updated list, or the same list with parameters to indicate which part of the list to use.  This is using your servlet as a controller; you should avoid using JSP files (presentation) as controllers.  While this seems complicated now, you'll find it makes your JSP (and other presentation) pages much easier to write.

Comment: The list did not change at all from the original, but how can I retrieve that original list? I need to have the user click the next button on the JSP page before I go back to the arraylist

Comment: The question is rather vague.  But you could keep track of the array list in a session, and then return it each time you make a request of the servlet.  But there's an infinite number of ways to do this.

Comment: The problem is, When keeping track of the arraylist, the JSP file that holds it temporarily before it sends it to the new servlet produces an error. The JSP can open hold the arraylist from the first servlet, but the 2nd servlet can not open the same arraylist when it is sent from the JSP

Comment: Are you familiar with sessions?  If not, you might want to read about those.  Sessions can be used to retain information from one servlet invocation to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpSession`. Store `ArrayList` as session attribute from original Servlet before passing it to `JSP`. Then again When you call another `Servlet` from that `JSP`. You should get `Arraylist` from `HttpSession`.

**Another not but recommended way is to serialize values and then send it back again to Servlet.**

If there is a small amount of data like String, integers etc. in the `ArrayList`, you could do

```
public String serializeArrayList(ArrayList list){
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    sb.append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"list_values\" value=\"");
    sb.append(list.get(i));
    sb.append("\">\n");
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Then build a new list using `request.getParameterValues("list_values")` which returns a `String[]` and again build ArrayList

This, of course, won't be very efficient if you have dozens or hundreds of entries in the list and also if you have objects stored in the `ArrayList`

Comment: I would have max 20 strings in the arraylist, but there are about 5 array lists.

Comment: @ShivamKumar: Then go for Session.